# jQuery Mobile - How to resize my image from server to fit in listview image box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

When I call and load an image from the server into my listview, it turns out that the desired image does not fit the picture box. Images obtained from different servers have different sizes.

My HTML :

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="listdata">

</ul>
```

My jQuery :

```
$.ajax({
   type : 'GET',
   url : 'http://api.bacaberita.com/app/bacaberita/utama.html',
   async: true,
   dataType : 'json',
    success : function(result){
       allData = result.items;
       $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
       $.each(allData, function(i, data) {
           $('#listdata').append(
               '<li>' +
                   '<a href="#">' +
                       '<img src="'+ data.Img +'">' +
                       '<h2>'+ data.Title +'</h2>' +
                       '<p>'+ data.Post +'</p>' +
                   '</a>' +
               '</li>'
           );
       });
       $("#listdata").listview("refresh");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        alert('Connection trouble [Error Code : initApp]');
    }
});
```

Result :

[image]

Size of my picture about ex: 600x300.

How do I get jQuery Mobile can easily create 80x80 sizes in order to fit the image

Comment: Set height & width of image tag

Comment: ^^This.  Ugly, but true.  Ideally you'd be writing the server code yourself so you could resize there, but that's in a perfect world and I guess not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your rep...Nice help...:) It is supposed to be from a server that provides images with this size. But the web application has been running and already there are hundreds of images on the server. Only the most convenient way

Comment: I'd recommend just putting a height attribute on the image element.  Not ideal, but it will work.  (If you're not aware, it will automatically resize the width to suit whatever height you use, so don't worry about that value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your images are square, they will be automatically resized to 80x80 and will fit nicely.

If they are rectangular and of different length to width ratios, they will be resized, but won't line up nicely.  In this case you can play with CSS to center the re-sized images horizontally and vertically, so at least they line up nicely.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/SeMG4/1/)**

Give the `<UL>` a class that can be used in the CSS (`has-odd-thumb`). In the `<LI>`, I have created a container for the thumbnail image that can be absolutely positioned and have the image centered:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="has-odd-thumb">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="thumbContainer">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/food/1" />
            </div>
            <h2>Food</h2>
            <p>600 x 300 sized icon</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS then positions the thumbnail container on the left, centers the image using `margin: auto` and padds the anchor so that text does not overlap the image.

```
.has-odd-thumb li a {
    padding-left: 90px !important;
}
.thumbContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 90px;
}
.thumbContainer img {
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 78px;
}
```